# Receiving error when trying to run my program

Tags: java

I am receiving the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3   50" in the code below. And I am having a hard time solving it. Could anyone possibly shed some light on what it could be from? From my understanding it usually means the error is in line 3 and line 50 correct?

```
 package report.generator;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class ReportGenerator
 {


     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\sprocketorders.txt"));
            String line;
            String element[] = new String[2];
            int   sum[] = new int[5];
            File file = new File ("C:\\sprocketordersreport.txt");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                element = line.split(" ");

                switch(Integer.parseInt(element[0]))
                {
                    case 1:
                        sum[0] = sum[0] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sum[1] = sum[1] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sum[2] = sum[2] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        sum[3] = sum[3] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sum[4] = sum[4] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Spacely Sprockets\nTaking Sprockets into the Future\nSales Summary Report\nSprocket Number Total Quantity Sold\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++)
                bw.write((i + 1) + "\t" + sum[i] + "\n");

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally
        {
           try
            {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
          }

      }
```

This program is to take an input from a text file and output the information in a report format.

EDIT: Here is the input file info. After looking at it, it looks like this may be where the problem is coming from. But I'm not entirely sure.

3   50

2   20

2   100

5   15

1   90

5   85

4   300

2   35

3   100

It's not formatting it exactly as it is in the text file. There are more spaces between the integers on the left and those on the right.

Comment: You would get NumberFormatException if the supplied value is not a valid number. Try to debug and see the values on all lines Integer.parseInt()

Comment: No. Show us the strace trace associated with the exception, THAT will contain the offending line number.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt() is most likely throwing that because the number you're trying to parse isn't in the right format, take a look at the string you're trying to read from you might spot the error then

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
The problem appears to come from your input file having blank lines between the lines that contain numbers.

Comment: ...added the info to the post

Comment: If your input file is double spaced, after the first pair of numbers is parsed correctly, it will fall over because it's trying to parse a blank line into an int. I was wrong about the space between the numbers - your line.split(" ") deals with that just fine.

Comment: Yeah, confirmed - it runs fine without the double-spacing.

Comment: So you're saying that if I delete the extra space between integers in my text file I should be good?

Comment: The extra space between the lines, not between the 2 integers on each line.